# How to extract specific data from JSON encoded string

Tags: php, json, wordpress, server

I am writing some code and when I echo this code

```
echo json_encode($_SERVER);
```

I get this output

```
{
    "HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE":"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT":"WordPress\/5.7.2; https:\/\/dvsucb.local",
    "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT":1625414926.336319,
    "REQUEST_TIME":1625414926
}
```

I want to extract the URL inside HTTP_USER_AGENT that will be: https://dvscucb.local

I want to extract only the URL not the WordPress version. How to get this ?

Comment: Do you want to get the URL?

Comment: @mfort, exactly, only the URL

Comment: What does JSON have to do with any of this? The `$_SERVER` array contains the string you want to parse - why would you encode it to JSON in the first place?

Comment: ..or wordpress and server (which is for questions about servers, not PHP's $_SERVER tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `json_encode()` here.

You can access the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` property from the `$_SERVER` array, and then use a regular expression to extract the URL from the string.

Here is a fairly simple example:

```php
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (preg_match("/WordPress\/[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+;\s(.*)/", $userAgent, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```